# Convert XML to DataSet with rows

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I have an xml file like this:

```
<result>
  <customer>
     <id>1</id>
     <name>A</name>
  </customer>
  <customer>
     <id>2</id>
     <name>B</name>
  </customer>
</result>
```

So I need that data filled on a DataSet, here is my code:

```
 var reader = new StringReader(xmldoc.InnerXml);
 dsDatos.ReadXml(reader);
```

The problem is that it's filling the dataset with two Tables each one with a single row. But I need a single Table with the two rows.

What am I doing wrong?

PD: I'm using C# and I don't want to iterate through the XML file, I want to use the ReadXml method.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that by using `.InnerXml`, you're only reading the two customer elements and not the root element.

Since that means you have two root elements, it's splitting them into two tables.

Try using `xmldoc.OuterXml`.